# How to delete CGRect in Swift?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift2

I'm developing macOS app. I need an ability to delete a created CGRect object.

```
let rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by delete? What do you mean by compiled app?

Comment: I mean create an object in app and then delete it (not in Xcode IB).
compiled = final project

Comment: Please first try to understand what a `CGRect` is.

Comment: Since the username "Swift" will be leading to confusion, you should change it probably to Jonathan or Tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGRect cannot be deleted since it is just a type of a size, struct and cannot be displayed straight on your UI. (it will be deleted automatically when it goes out of scope in your code.)
A CGRect could be assigned as the frame of a **UIView**(in iOS)/NSView that can be added to the screen and be deleted later using a reference.
If you want to delete a frame of a view, just assign the frame a `CGRect.zero`.
That wont delete the frame but will make the frame to stick to the top left corner of the screen and have a height and width equal to zero.

Comment: Arbel, maybe I can use Undo button (NSUndoManager) instead Delete one?

Comment: @Swift What exactly do you want to delete?, the view assigned to that frame, the frame assigned to the view or the view itself.

Comment: The frame assigned to the view.

Comment: @Swift If you want to delete the frame assign it like that: view.frame = CGRect.zero, if you want to delete the entire view: view.removeFromSuperview(), note that the CGRect.zero doesn't delete the view. it still still there just located in CGRect(0,0,0,0) with the size or (width:0,height:0)

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete it. CGRect is an struct which contains a dimensions and position of a rectangle. In swift you can reset that CGRect

```
var rectangle = CGRectZero
```